# ggvis, Error in normalizedPath()

Tags: r, ggvis

I am running one of the "interactive" examples from the ggvis webpage (http://ggvis.rstudio.com/ggvis-basics.html#introduction) and I obtain an error.

I loaded the ggvis, dplyr and shiny packages.

Here is the code that I ran:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt) %>% layer_histograms(binwidth = input_slider(0, 2, step = 0.1))
```

And here is the output that I get.

```
Showing dynamic visualisation. Press Escape/Ctrl + C to stop.
Error in normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : 
  path[1]="/Builds/CRAN-QA-Simon/packages/mavericks-x86_64/Rlib/3.1/ggvis/www/ggvis": No such file or directory
```

I am using RStudio Version 0.98.507, and R version 3.1.0; Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit).

Comment: Does this path exist on your computer?

Comment: I'm guessing a Windows problem as I get the same error.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker, maybe, as I don't get this error with Linux.

Comment: Please install 0.3.0.1 or from github. It was a bug that slipped through :(

Comment: Installing it from github worked. Thanks Hadley!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a similar thing trying to run a shiny app from RStudio.

My workaround was to `devtools::install_packages("rstudio/ggvis")`.

I'll put a link to this from the ggvis google group.

Hope this helps

Comment: After loading devtools, I used install_github("rstudio/ggvis").